# Ремень — от немецкого Riemen?

Tags: этимология

Правда ли, что слово *ремень* произошло от немецкого Riemen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно этимологи **очень осторожны в своих высказываниях**, если речь идет о словах с неясным происхождением, для которых отсутствует общепринятое мнение. **Их обычная риторика** – весьма возможно, вероятно, не исключено и т. д.

Итак, что можно сказать о связи этих слов: русского слова ***ремень***  и немецкого ***Riemen*** (материал изложен по словарю П.Я. Черных).

1) В славянских языках (болг., чеш., словен, польск.) существуют подобные формы слова. **О.-с. корень rem.** Можно предположить, что **форма ременъ – вторичная,** начальная форма ***remy.*** Форма ременъ не была устойчивой (по крайней мере, единственной), что видно по существованию в русских говорах таких слов, как ***ремук, ремуха, ремуга.***

2) **Происхождение о.-с. корня rem неясно.** Не исключено (хотя и сомнительно), что здесь мы имеем дело **со старым заимствованием из немецкого языка:**  riomo – лента, пояс, (др.-нем.), также reoma (англосакс.), rem (норв., дат, швед.)

3) Напротив, **современное немецкое Riemen**, возможно, является заимствованием из славянских языков.

4) **Но происхождение др.-нем. корня тоже неясно.** Существует предположение, что есть связь с и.-е. корнем ***reu*** – рвать.

**Вывод.** Таким образом, связь слов, несомненно, существует, но вот какова она – этот вопрос остается пока открытым.

**Приложение** [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Черных,_Павел_Яковлевич](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85,_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

**Па́вел Я́ковлевич Черны́х (1896 — 1970)** — советский языковед и педагог, доктор филологических наук (1954), профессор Московского государственного университета им. М. В. Ломоносова. Г**лавным трудом его жизни стал «Историко-этимологический словарь русского языка» — единственная работа с 1955 года.** В 1961 году он прекращает педагогическую деятельность, чтобы сосредоточиться на составлении словаря. На момент начала работы Павел Яковлевич заметил, что словарь **А. Г. Преображенского** (1914,1944) устарел, словарь **М. Фасмера** (1950—1958) отличается некоторым субъективизмом в отборе и толковании слов, «Краткий этимологический словарь» **Н. М. Шанского** (издан в 1961 г.) имеет ограниченный словник.

Answer (score 3):

Солгали Вам, неправда это.

Когда этимология слова затруднена, честный немец Фасмер так и говорит: ***происхождение тёмное***. А тут ему светло-пресветло - к праславянскому (а затем к древнерусскому) нас отсылает, а "герм." заклеймляет позором и нехорошими словами (выделено болдом):

**[РЕМЕНЬ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)**

> Происходит от праслав. *rеmу (род. п. *rеmеnе), от кот. в числе
>   прочего произошли: др.-русск. ремыкъ (Пандекты Никона), ремень
>   (Изборн. Святосл. 1073 г., полоцк. грам. 1330 г. и др.), ст.-слав.
>   ремень (др.-греч. ἱμάς), русск. ремень, укр. ре́мінь, болг. ре́мен,
>   реми́к, ре́мък, сербохорв. ре̏ме̑н (род. -мена), рѐмик, словенск.
>   rémen, -ẹ́nа наряду с jérmen, -ẹ́na, чешск. řemen, словацк. remeň,
>   польск. rzemień, в.-луж. rjemjeñ, н.-луж. ŕeḿeń. **Ввиду ст.-слав.
>   примеров и древних особенностей словообразования заимствование из
>   герм. (ср. др.-в.-нем. riumо «ремень», ср.-в.-нем. rieme) невозможно.**
>   В противном случае ожидалось бы *rjumenь. Более удачна мысль о
>   первонач. знач. «ремень ярма» и родстве с греч. ἀραρίσκω «соединяю»,
>   ἁρμός «член», лат. arma «доспехи, утварь, оружие», armentum «крупный
>   рогатый скот», а также с ярмо́.

Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

---

Чуть понятнее - для школьников - говорит [Успенский](https://lexicography.online/etymology/uspensky/%D1%80/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C):

> **Реме́нь.** Надо полагать, что в праславянском языке этот предмет именовался так: «ремы», родительный падеж «реме́не», винительный —
>   «реме́нь». Точно так же наше «камень» некогда был винительным падежом
>   от праславянского «камы». Вероятно, первоначально слово «ремы»
>   обозначало не всякую кожаную ленту, а только особую завязку из кожи на
>   упряжном ярме вола, так сказать «яремный ремень».
>
> Потом значение его расширилось. Но основа у этих двух слов — «ремень»
>   и «ярмо» — одна, хотя и в двух разных вариантах.

[Шанский](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%80/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C) с ними не спорит, "общеславянское", говорит:

> **Реме́нь.** Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. -men, ср. камень, пламя и т. д.), очевидно, того же корня (с метатезой er > re), что ярмо,
>   лат. arma «доспехи», греч. armos «член», arariskō «соединяюсь». Ремень
>   буквально — «то, что соединяет, совчленяет, скрепляет».